# angular2 component load problems

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Today I ran into some strange behaviour in Angular.

I have an application which works with an API to get data from a server.
Below are the Code Parts which are important for my Problem I guess.

I get an JSON with different IDs, after I use one of the IDs to get to the Detail page of the ID. On this page I use the `goback()` function to get to the list again.

On the first load the API data gets saved without any problem, after going back the var `tempPromotion` stays empty. I got zero console error.

What could be the Problem?

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
     // This is where i save the data from the API Call 
    this.promotionListService.getList().then((data) => {
        this.tempPromotion = data;
        this.tempPromotion = this.tempPromotion['response_payload'];
        console.log(this.tempPromotion);
    });
}

    // This is the back Method which is called after a button click
goback() {
    this.location.back();
}


   //Get List Method define the API call
getList(): Promise<any> {

    let Id = '1';
    let serviceDec = "PromotionList";

    return this.ApiClientService.getAPIObject(Id, serviceDec);
}


   // get APIObject makes the call
getAPIObject(param: string, serviceDec: string) {

    // Header mit Key aus LocalStorage
    var header =  new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // immer zu erst Content-Type
    header.append('x-api-key', this.key);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
    var urlTemp = this.url;
    switch (serviceDec) {

        case 'voucher':
            urlTemp  = urlTemp.concat('?promotionId='+param);
            return this.http.get(urlTemp, options)
                .toPromise()
                .then((response: Response) => response.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);

        case 'PromotionList':
            urlTemp =  API_CLIENT[2];
            return this.http.get(urlTemp, options)
                .toPromise()
                .then((response: Response) => response.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);

        case 'salesChannelList':
            urlTemp =  API_CLIENT[3].concat('?mode='+param);;
            return this.http.get(urlTemp, options)
                .toPromise()
                .then((response: Response) => response.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);


        default:
            console.error('An error occurred. Wrong service declaration.');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `getList()` return an observable? If so you need to subscribe to it like this:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
     // This is where i save the data from the API Call 
    this.promotionListService.getList().subscribe((data) => {
        this.tempPromotion = data;
        this.tempPromotion = this.tempPromotion['response_payload'];
        console.log(this.tempPromotion);
    });
}
```

It is important to remember that Observables do not actually fire a request off to the API until they are `subscribe`ed to. So until you setup the subscription you'll never receive any data from the observable. Which would explain why you weren't getting any errors either.

Comment: `getList()` returns an Promise

Comment: I see, have you verified that your list component is being rebuilt when you go back? For some reason your component may be persisting between routes which would mean ngOnInit is only running when the page is initially loaded then sitting stagnant. I don't know why your tempPromotion property would be empty though.

Comment: Can you post the `getList()` function?

Comment: Could you explain how i rebuilt the component? Anyway i added more Code to my Question